# Optimize Eigen expression by adding operation

Tags: c++, optimization, eigen, eigen3

on my machine MSVC (build in release), calculation  1 in the following code is much faster than calculation 2 (6s vs 8.5s). Why is this the case?

Here's the complete code (main.cpp):

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

int main()
{
    Matrix3Xf a = Matrix3Xf::Random(3, 400);
    Vector3f v = Vector3f::Random();
    RowVectorXf b = RowVectorXf::Random(400);

    auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    for (float f = 0; f < 1000000; f++)
    {
        // calculation 1:
        //b.noalias() += (v.transpose() * (a * 1));

        // calculation 2:
        b.noalias() += (v.transpose() * a);
    }

    auto end = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    cout << "Elapsed time in milliseconds : "
        << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count()
        << " ms" << endl;

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the CMakeLists.txt to reproduce

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(testProject)

# Set a default build type if none was specified
if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE AND NOT CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES)
    message(STATUS "Setting build type to 'Release' as none was specified.")
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release CACHE STRING "Choose the type of build." FORCE)
    # Set the possible values of build type for cmake-gui
    set_property(CACHE CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE PROPERTY STRINGS "Debug" "Release"
        "MinSizeRel" "RelWithDebInfo")
endif()

find_package(Eigen3 3.3.7 NO_MODULE)

set(SOURCES main.cpp )

add_executable(testProject ${SOURCES} ${SOURCES_test})

target_link_libraries (testProject PUBLIC Eigen3::Eigen)
```

Comment: because "calculation 1" is just a comment? Seriously, how did you measure, how did you compile? Optimizations enabled? Please add some more info to the question.

Comment: any decent compiler should realize that your loop is equivalent to `auto temp = (v.transpose() *a); b+= 1000000 *  temp;`. I bet you are looking at a debug build

Comment: @user463035818 Can you really be sure of that, with Eigen doing possibly intrisincs and cache blocking in the middle?

Comment: @user463035818 I'm building in release. Of course I'm not measuring the time of a comment.... I'm executing once with calculation 1 commented out and once with calculation 2

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher the only thing I am sure of is that OP should tell us how they compile :P. No I am not sure at all, though the loop is of rather simple structure ala `for (float f=0;f < 100000; f++) { do_something_that_does_not_depend_on_f(); }`

Comment: what compiler flags do you use?

Comment: @user463035818  /O2  /D NDEBUG and lots of others that cmake sets by default, if you build in release mode

Comment: Why on earth would you strip the includes and `main` declaration before posting? You are only saving maybe 5 lines and killing any motivation readers might have to experiment and help you. [mcve] and exact compiler command are recommended for a reason.

Comment: Try `b.noalias() += (v.transpose() * a);` and I agree with @MarcGlisse, you should provide an MCVE.

Comment: @user463035818 I guess you expect a bit much from the compiler. E.g., it would need to figure out that there is no overlapping memory. Also, without fast-math optimizations this is not exactly the same: Adding the same value 1000000 times gives rounding errors at every addition (the last values might not even change the result anymore).

Comment: @chtz ,user463035818 I added the complete code and the CmakeLists.txt to reproduce the build. If you don't want to use cmake, choose your build system of choise and use the default "release" flags, it will be very similar. 

.noalias() didn't give a measurable effekt on for me

Comment: Thanks for posting the code. At least with gcc on linux I see the same running time for both versions, so the analysis needs to look specifically at what visual studio is doing.

Comment: @yar If you want some of insight as to what MSVC is doing (vs. e.g. gcc) you can have a look at the assembly [here](https://godbolt.org/z/bauX3E).

Comment: @AviGinsburg You should really pass big objects by reference: https://godbolt.org/z/eCaPfZ But this actually shows that MSVC (once again) fails to inline some functions (if you switch to the 3.3.x version of Eigen: https://godbolt.org/z/dcYt_G)

Comment: @chtz Cool! How did you choose the version of Eigen? (sometimes == once again...)

Comment: @AviGinsburg Click on the "libraries" button, then on the up/down arrows near the library you want to include.

Comment: @chtz Found it. Conformance viewer.

Comment: @AviGinsburg ,chtz, thanks for the code examples! I did not expect mSVC to be that bad.... I always had the impression that it actually generates faster code than gcc